# In Postfix, how do I block sending emails to other domains while allowing forwarding of one email address?

Tags: centos, postfix, centos7, mail-forwarding

I just installed PostFix on Cent OS 7.  I want to set up mail forwarding from an admin address to my Gmail account but I also want to block all emails that are sent to emails that are not addressed to that admin account.  At the bottom of my /etc/postfix/main.cf file, I have

```
virtual_alias_domains = example.com
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual

transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
```

From that same machine, if I send this email, its not received

```
echo "This is the body of the email" | mail -s "admin line 2" admin@example.com
```

However, if I comment out the last line above (the "transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport" line), then the email goes through.  How do I block emails sent to other domains but also keep my forwarding in place?  The /etc/postfix/virtual file contains

```
admin@example.com myemail@gmail.com
```

and the file /etc/postfix/transport contains

```
example.com    :
*              discard:
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this in transport, look at the recipient list

In main.cf

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/recipient_access
```

in /etc/postfix/recipient_access

```
admin@example.com OK
* DISCARD
```